# Linked List implementation for a stack

Tags: algorithm, linked-list, stack, doubly-linked-list

Here is my implemetation of stack with linkedlist

```
STACK using linked list 

STACK-EMPTY:
if L.head == NIL
    return True
else return False

PUSH(x):
x.next = L.head 
if L.head != NIL
    L.head.prev = x
L.head = x
x.prev = NIL

POP():
x = L.head
L.head = x.next
x.next.prev = L.head
return x
```

would you validate this? how to improve ?

thanks

Comment: Any particular reason you used a double-linked list for this? You can implement a stack with a single-linked list, as there's no need for a prev pointer.

Comment: Seems like a question for codereview.SE

Comment: thanks was not awareofit

Answer (score 1):

You can improvement the consistency of your data structure:

1. The `prev` of the list head is always `NIL`
2. An element which is not in the list has `next` and `prev` set to NIL

Taking 1. in account your POP has an inconsistency which can be source of errors: When you pop an element the `prev` of the head is the head itself, when you push an element the `prev` of the head is NIL.

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

Definitions:

- `S.top` is a pointer to some node of type `X` at the top of the stack
- `X` is a node having two pointers, `top` and `base`
- `X.top` points to the next node toward the top of the stack.
- `X.base` points to the next node toward the base of the stack (bottom)

First initialize the stack top pointer:

```
STACK-INITIAL:
S.top = NIL
return true  // Never fails
```

Test for empty stack:

```
STACK-EMPTY:
return (S.top == NIL)
```

Push node `x` on stack:

```
PUSH(x):
x.top = NIL     // Top of stack, therfore top is NIL
x.base = S.top  // base is previous top
S.top = x       // x is now top of stack  
return true
```

Pop and return top of stack (this is the only 'interesting' part):

```
POP():
x = S.top          // Top node on stack (could be NIL)
if S.top != NIL    // Check in case stack was empty
  S.top = x.base   // New top = next node toward base
  x.base = NIL     // Disconnect x from stack
  if S.top != NIL  // Is stack now empty?
    S.top.top = NIL // No, set top node's top pointer to NIL
return x            // x could be NIL if stack was empty
```

Something to think about... I used a double linked list above because
it looked like that is what you were using. However, you only need a
single linked list where the links point to the base of the stack.
Notice that the `x.top` pointers in the above algorithm are pretty much
useless (set but never referenced). As long as you keep track of the stack top (S.top) the only thing
you need to do is trace back down the stack during POP operations.

**Response to comments**

When an element is poped off of the stack, all of its associated
pointers should be set to NIL. This is because it is no longer part
of the stack so should not point to any stack elements. I added that bit
to my original answer (see above).

In a similar manner, the new top of stack element (unless the stack becomes empty)
needs to have its pointer to the element above it
set to NIL (since the element above it was removed). 
In my example that is what the `S.top.top = NIL`
stuff was all about (`S.top` points to the top stack element so `S.top.top` is the
top pointer of that element). I think you would do the same with `x.next.prev = NIL`, 
assuming `x` is the element you POPed and is not NIL itself. In your pseudocode it looks
like `x.next.prev = L.head` would leave the prev pointer of the top of stack element pointing to itself
since `L.head` was set to `x.next` (the new top of stack just before that).

Finally, I question why would use a double linked list to
implement a stack, only a single linked list with pointers to the
next element below it are required

Comment: In my pseudocode, `L.head` points to first element in stack, so that `x.next = L.head ` comes down to `x.base = S.top `. `L.head = x` is equivalent to your `S.top = x ` and then `x.top = NIL` is my `x.prev = NIL`, which I can put in the very end, right ?

Comment: but i think that i do also need to make prev (top) pointer for previous-first element in stack to point to x, with my `if L.head != NIL
    L.head.prev = x`. So: could you confirm my code is correct, AND, isn't this last statement mandatory in PUSH() method ?? thanks a lot

Comment: in the same flavour, isn't it that `x.next.prev = L.head` is mandatory for POP() ? thanks

Comment: @macscholes See Response to Comments in answer