# 'pop' method in Ruby

Tags: ruby, linked-list, stack, nodes

I've created a 'pop' method to take the last node off of a linked list. However, the issue I'm receiving is that it's not removing the node, it's simply telling me the data in the node that should be removed.

I should preface with I'm using test driven development and the test was written to say 'assert_equal "blop", list.pop. "blop" is the value of the last node. It's great that I got my method to tell me that, but it still doesn't remove the node.

```
def pop
 @count -= 1
 return_string = ""
 current_node = @head
 until current_node.next_node == nil
  current_node = current_node.next_node
 end
 return_string << current_node.data + " "
 return_string.strip
 current_node.next_node = Node.new(data)
end
```

My question is how do I return the value of what's being removed, as well as, removing the value from the linked list.

Comment: Keep in mind the only things that are logically false in Ruby are `nil` and `false`, so unless you're expecting literal `false` in your list, then `if current_node.next_node` is the way to express that. You can probably also do `current_node &&= current_node.next_node`.

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
until current_node.next_node == nil
    current_node = current_node.next_node
end
```

When that loop finishes, `current_node` is pointing to the last node (the node for which the next node is `nil).

That's the node you should remove, but in order to remove that one, you should point the previous node's `next_node` to `nil`.

However, at that point you don't have a reference to the previous node.

You could have another variable to track the `previous` node so that you can then remove it once you exit the loop.

You can check this related question (not Ruby specific) for ideas on the algorithm.

[Linked List implementation for a stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15659557/linked-list-implementation-for-a-stack)

As a side note, one of the answers on that one implements this as making `pop` remove the first node of the list (and `push` add the node to the beginning), which makes it easier (and faster, since you don't go over the whole list each time).